# Setting up intranet web server to send e-mails

Tags: iis, smtp, windows-server

All I want to do is have an ability for my intranet web server to send e-mails.

I'm trying to set up the SMTP to listen on port 25 while the websites are on port 80.

I think I might have something that could work (after following a tutorial) but I'm missing a key piece of information. Each site describing how to set up an SMTP server falls short of telling me where I need to go to set up a new e-mail account for this SMTP.

Without it I can't use the powershell lines of code to see if I've set it up correctly (I don't have a "from" to use).

```
Send-MailMessage 
–From ???@[Servers Intranet IP]:25 
–To recipient@recipientdomain.com 
–Subject “Test Email” 
–Body “Test E-mail (body)” 
-SmtpServer [Servers Intranet IP]:25
```

Note I don't know if [Servers Intranet IP]:25 is correct or not but I get a feeling if I can answer how to create the "From" then that piece of information will fall into place. The sites can be accessed internally using `[someText].[otherText].net:80` and `[Servers Intranet IP]:80`

Note: I manage my website using IIS Manager (Version 10.0.14393.0) but the tutorial I followed for creating my SMTP forced me to go use IIS 6.0 Manager. The SMTP virtual server wasn't showing up in IIS Manager (V 10).

Note: In IIS 6.0 Manager, [SMTP Virtual Server #1] has a Domain Name `[someText].[otherText].net` and Type `Local (Default)` and it is running.

If this is too obvious, dumb, or makes 0 sense so much so that I deserve a -1 please tell me why and then give me a -1.

More info.

```
PS C:\Users\[UserName]> Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 25).OwningProcess

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    545      49    16112      27040       0.73   6340   0 inetinfo
```

Comment: To set up smtp user, you only need create local user. Nothing special. To set IIS SMTP, you need to set DNS and network correctly. Besides, why did you use [server ip] in From parameter? Since SMTP virtual server belong to legacy IIS 6, why don't you use modern app like exchange?

Comment: Thanks I'll start looking into Exchange. Reason was because most of my research kept pointing to tutorials on SMTP virtual server as the solution for adding e-mail capabilities to a web server.